# How to replace contents of one cell I2 with contents of J2 throughout worksheet up to 1000 rows

Tags: vba, replace, find

I wonder if there is a VBA for this?? I need to find up to 1000 strings of text and replace with data from the next column through the worksheet. To better explain, I need to find contents of cell I2 and replace with contents of cell J2. Then find contents of cell I3 and replace with contents of cell J3, I4 with J4 and so on up to I1000 with J1000, or more. All of this needs to be done on worksheet named "R Replaced". Can anyone help me?

Comment: Show a sample of your data. Are just replacing everything in "I2" for example or are you replacing a part of it? If just a part of it, how is the part identified? Are there blank cells in columns "I" or "J"? What have you tried so far, can you post it?

Comment: I think I responded in the wrong place, as it is titled, "1 Answer". Anyway, if you like you can check out my response. Any help you can give would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your response. Attached you'll find a screen-shot. We need to search all of column L, for contents of individual cells in column I and replace with contents of cells on the same row in column J. Currently we do this step manually. In the case of the screen-shot attached, we would first paste the contents of cell I2 in the "find what" text box (as shown) and then copy the contents of J2 into "Replace with", then select column L and click "Replace All". We then would search for contents of I3 and replace with contents of J3, in column L, then contents of J4 with I4, and so on. Columns I and J usually contain from 200 to 1000 skus to be updated. Column L has nearly 100,000 skus.

I hope this is clear. Thanks ahead of time for your assistance. Much appreciated!
[screen-shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQcb9.jpg)